# How to insert values into sheet from a UserForm in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, forms

This is my first time creating a form so very new to it.

I have the following form:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
'add all options for the different funds
With Me.ComboBox1
    .Clear
    .AddItem "Main Fund"
    .AddItem "Quant Fund"
End With

With Me.ComboBox2
    .Clear
    .AddItem "January"
    .AddItem "February"
    .AddItem "March"
    .AddItem "April"
    .AddItem "May"
    .AddItem "June"
    .AddItem "July"
    .AddItem "August"
    .AddItem "September"
    .AddItem "October"
    .AddItem "November"
    .AddItem "December"
End With

With Me.ComboBox3
    .Clear
    .AddItem "PnL"
    .AddItem "Number of employees"
    .AddItem "Number of positions"
End With

End Sub
```

Which looks like:

[image]

The usage of the form is:

1. A user in the worksheet, selects a cell
2. The user call the CallForm subroutine and the form appears
3. The user inputs the three arguments and the corresponding data from the following excel sheet is inserted int the selected cell:

[image]

```
Sub CallForm()
    MyForm.Show
End Sub
```

Please let me know if any clarification is needed or if i've missed out important information, any help would be fab since i've tried googling but really need help.

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is?

Comment: How to use the form input to select the corresponding data from the activesheet and insert it into the activecell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a range in the sheet and set it to the value in your userform under the subroutine for pushing the "insert" button, e.g.:

```
Sub commandbutton1_click()
    With sheets("nameOfSheet")
        .cells(7,15).value = Me.Combobox1.text
    End with
End sub
```

All of the standard ways of finding your range apply, e.g., `Find()` or `Match()`.